# Unable to connect secondary display on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Zephyrus G15

Tags: display

I have been trying to connect my external monitor via HDMI, but ubuntu never detects it. I have tried updating the graphics card driver, installed bumblebee changing to older version of graphics card, but it doesnt seem to work. Kindly assist me.

Comment: Same issue here on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Zephyrus G15, following